# django table cell color based on expression

Tags: python, django

python 2.6, with Django 1.3.1 on Redhat 6.3

In Django how would I go about changing the background colour of a table cell depending on it's value, as in if it is over 10 it's red, between 7 and 9 it's orange, below 7 is green etc..

The data is coming from a non django database/model.

I am using a standard template to iterate over the table, but would have no problem using a custom template for this.

I see the following

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834618/set-background-color-for-a-field-depending-on-its-value)

that deals with changing cell colour but it seems to be based on a concrete value in the cell as opposed to being within a range.

using the following test code for a view

```
def dashboard(request):
  if request.user.is_authenticated():
      user = request.user.first_name
  else:
      return redirect('/bcpm/login')


  table_headers = ['Colmun1','Column2','Column3']
  table_data = [['test1',2,3],['test2',2,4],['test3',5,5]]
  page_title = 'Dashboard'

  template_dict = {'header_list':table_headers, 'page_title':page_title,
                         'results':table_data,'username':user}
  return render_to_response('dashboard.html',template_dict)enter code here
```

and the following generic table template:

```
<table border=1 width=98% style="margin-left:12px;">
        <tr>
            {% for item in header_list %}
            <th>{{ item }}</th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>


            {% for row in results %}
            <tr>
                {% for line in row %}
                <td>{{line}}</td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}

    </table>
```

Thanks.

---

Almost solved;

With the help of brianbuck below i came up with the following,
in the view:

```
def dashboard(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        user = request.user.first_name
    else:
       return redirect('/login'

    table_headers = ['Column1','Column2','Column3']
    table_data = [['name','thing',8],['name','thing',5]]
    page_title = 'Dashboard'

    template_dict = {'header_list':table_headers, 'page_title':page_title,
                         'results':table_data,'username':user}
    return render_to_response('dashboard.html',template_dict)
```

in the template;

```
<table border=1 width=68% style="margin-left:12px;">
        <tr>
            {% for item in header_list %}
            <th>{{ item }}</th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>


            {% for element in results %}
          <tr>
            <td> {{ element.0 }} </td>
            <td> {{ element.1 }} </td>
            {% if element.3 > 7 %} <td class="red"> {{ element.3 }} </td> 
            {% else %} <td class="green"> {{ element.3 }} </td> {% endif %}
          </tr>
            {% endfor %}

    </table>
{% endif %}
```

I really could not get it to do an {% if  or  %}
When I tried to set it up to do a

"greater than or equal to 7 or less than or equal to 8"

it would always evaluate to this expression for a number higher than 7, even though the first if statement should be true for anything higher than 9.

I am using Django 1.3 and I think there may be some limitations of the if/else and the multiple evaluations, either way I have it 80% working with two values red/green and that is good enough for the moment.

Thank you all.

---

Got it to work like this;

```
{% for element in results %}
            <tr>
            <td> {{ element.0 }} </td>
            <td> {{ element.1 }} </td>
            <td> {{ element.2 }} </td>
            <td> {{ element.3 }} </td>
            {% if element.4 > 8 %} <td class="red"> {{ element.4 }} </td>
            {% else %}{% if element.4 > 8 or element.4 >= 5 %} <td class="orange"> {{ element.4 }} </td>
            {%else %}{% if element.4 < 5 %}<td class="green"> {{ element.4 }} </td>
            {% endif %}{% endif %}{% endif %}

            <td> {{ element.5 }} </td>
```

This would not be required if you have a version of Django that supports elif or if you add some of the django snippets that are available to extend your django installation.

Hurrah.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This assumes you have three classes named:

```
td.red {
    backgroundColor: red;
}
td.orange {
    backgroundColor: orange;
}
td.green {
    backgroundColor: green;
}
```

...

Django 1.3 doesn't have `elif` so you will probably have to do it a bit more clunky.

```
<td class="
    {% if val >= 10 %}red{% endif %}
    {% if val >= 7 or val <= 9 %}orange{% endif %}
    {% if val < 7 %}green{% endif %}">
    {{ val }}
</td>
```

Comment: What about another if in an else branch?

Comment: i am sending the row as one list into the template, so there are text columns etc.. in there not everything will be numerical, although obviously at least one of the columns in the row will be

Comment: @möter, That's an interesting question, I suppose it depends on your preferred coding style.

Comment: if I do this {% for row in results %}
                <tr>
                    {% for line in row %}
                    <td class="red">
                        {{ line }}
                    </td> I am not getting a color change so i think i may have the definition in the incorrect place in the css, there is a section for tables and I have it in there. Sorry I am working from a css that I was given.

Comment: @AlanEnnis, You'll probably have to come up with a custom filter to test whether the value is an integer or not.

Comment: @AlanEnnis, Your CSS should be in a `<style>` tag above your table.

Comment: @brianbuck, sorry, to be specific. I am reusing the css that is part of the django admin page, this already has some table definitions so I have added the class definitions to those.

Comment: @brianbuck looks like the backgroundColor was the problem, when I changed it to just background it seems to be getting me somewhere. Thank you for the help, learned a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do this only in admin.py.

- Let's say your column is called `col` :
- You want to set the column to green if its value is bigger than 0 and to red if the opposite is true.

```
def TableAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)
    def col_(self, obj):
        green_style = "<script>document.querySelectorAll('.green_table_elem').forEach(elem => { elem.parentElement.style.background = 'green'; })</script>"
        red_style = "<script>document.querySelectorAll('.red_table_elem').forEach(elem => { elem.parentElement.style.background = 'red'; })</script>"
        
        if obj.col > 0:
            return mark_safe(f'<div class="green_table_elem">{obj.col}</div> {green_style}')
        else:
            return mark_safe(f'<div class="red_table_elem">{obj.col}</div> {red_style}')
    
    list_display = ('col_',)
```

This colors the `td` (column) itself and not the added div like some answers do.