# How to conditionally color table cells in Django Templates?

Tags: django, django-templates

I am passing default colors for the background cell and data from the model via context variables. But inside the template when I am parsing the model data, I want to conditionally color the individual cells.

```
<tr><td style="background-color:{{tarcol}};">{{poll.target}}</td></tr>
<tr><td style="background-color:{{actcol}};">{{poll.actual}}</td></tr>
```

The colors depend  on relative values of target & actual,so I have to compare the data to decide the color.
I am thinking I should not add logic to decide the colors in views, this must be done in the templates.
Is there a better way to handle this ??

p.s:I used this question as a inspiration for the design.
[django table cell color based on expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531332/django-table-cell-color-based-on-expression)

Answer (score 2):

I would relegate this task to a template tag to keep the templating as clean as possible. In a nutshell, you would create a template tag that accepts your context variables, decides the color and returns a string.

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/custom-template-tags/ for help and examples.

Answer (score 1):

First of all create custom admin change_list template where you load custom template tag:

```
{% load i18n grp_tags admin_urls admin_static admin_list my_admin_list %}
```

Copy existing admin_list.py and change:

```
        def items_for_result(cl, result, form):
            if f is None:
            ...                
            css_class = getattr(attr, 'css_class', False)
                if css_class:
                    row_class = mark_safe(' class="%s"' % css_class(result))

In admin.py have something like:

class Media:
        css = {
            'all': ('/static/custom_admin.css',)
        }
...

def job_driver_car(self, obj):
        return '{0} <strong>{1}</strong><br>{2}'.\
            format(obj.driver_type,
                   obj.driver_grade,
                   obj.car_type)
    job_driver_car.short_description = 'Driver / Car'
    job_driver_car.css_class = lambda obj: 'background lightyellow' \
        if obj.driver_grade is not None and 'NEW' in obj.driver_grade else ''
    job_driver_car.allow_tags = True
```

and css itself:

```
table tbody tr.grp-row-odd td.background, table tbody tr.grp-row-odd th.background,
table tbody tr.grp-row-even td.background, table tbody tr.grp-row-even th.background,
table tbody tr.grp-alt td.background, table tbody tr.grp-alt th.background {
    background: transparent;
}
.lightyellow { background: #ffd090 !important; }
```

I develop this solution because I needed to color almost every cell according to instance value. Checked on Django==1.6.2 and django-grappelli==2.5.2